# how to control version of data object (instance) in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, version

How would one set up the model in sqlalchemy to have a versioncontrol in the instance(column_version)?

Unique PK over Table.

Unique Version over PK.

Archive-Flag (latest version not archived).

e.g.

```
init= object:
--------------
*version;update;user;ID;archive;rest*

1;2012-01-01;userA; uniqueKey;no;data=green

on_update= object
--------------
*version;update;user;ID;archive;rest*

1;2012-01-01;userA; uniqueKey;**yes**;data=green

**2**;2012-01-05;userB; uniqueKey;no;data=red
```

Has somebody an idea on how to achieve that? or experience?

I Am thinking about two DB's right now (archive, active) where archive holds all the "old"versions (PK = UniqueKey+ Version) while active (pK = UniqueKey).

(for those who ask why should I do so?

Im thinking about difference between consistence &coherence mapping--> one could either map a specific version object1 version7 or the actual version object1).